# recovering from raid 10 single disk failiure

Tags: backup, raid10

I got a terastation with 4 disks in raid 10 setup. But one of them failed recently. Instead of inserting the disk and restructuring is it possible to copy the data to another disk outside the terastation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just copy the data the same way you would if the disk hadn't failed.

Comment: Because i only know the concept and this is my first time, if raid10 stripe the data to two disks is it possible to just copy from one disk ? is it readable ?

Comment: A four disk RAID 10 array replicates all data onto two disks, so the data can still be read if one disk fails. That's kind of the point of RAID 10 -- losing one disk doesn't stop you from operating.